# How can I get the number of Tweets a link has using the Twitter API?

Tags: twitter

I want to see how many tweets does a link have. For Facebook, you can use FQL to get the number of Likes each page has.

Is there a page in the Twitter API documentations that describe how to do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This seems to work, without authentication:

```
http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=example.com
```

For example, to get the number of tweets for [this random page on mashable](http://mashable.com/2012/01/21/top-10-tech-this-week-13/):

```
http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmashable.com%2F2012%2F01%2F21%2Ftop-10-tech-this-week-13
```

Returns the following JSON:

```
{"count":1204,"url":"http://mashable.com/2012/01/21/top-10-tech-this-week-13/"}
```

Comment: This appears to be deprecated in v1.1; and with v1 being retired on 7th May this year, does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve the same functionality?

Comment: What about v1.1? Somebody know how to it?

Comment: Has been [deprecated](https://blog.twitter.com/2015/hard-decisions-for-a-sustainable-platform) as as Nov 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter hasn't released any developer APIs for analytics based on links (assuming you're only interested in links that are wrapped by the t.co wrapper). You can look at the [existing documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tco-link-wrapper/faq#How_do_I_provide_my_users_with_analytics_about_the_links_they_share_on_Twitter) but it's not very good.

I don't believe there will be any API for getting the number of tweets that link to an arbitrary url.